# NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: iphone, ios

could you please help me to solve the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

```
array_Info = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
array_Info = [dict_Temp objectForKey:@"Children"];

NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.array_Info];

            int ran, arrayIndexing = 0;
            while ([temp count] != 0)
            {
                ran = arc4random();
                if(ran < 0)
                    ran*=-1;
                ran = ran % [temp count];

                if([temp count] == 1)
                    ran = 0;

                NSLog(@"%d  %d",arrayIndexing,ran);

                [self.array_Info replaceObjectAtIndex:arrayIndexing withObject:[temp objectAtIndex:ran]];

                [temp removeObjectAtIndex:ran];
                arrayIndexing++;
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

Presuming that `array_Info` is the backing variable for the `self.array_Info` property, you should change your second line to:

```
array_Info = [[dict_Temp objectForKey:@"Children"] mutableCopy];
```

This will give you the mutable array you need for the `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` call.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `self.array_Info` is an immutable array. Make it mutable.

Comment: That doesn't make it a mutable array, you are just writing over it.  Use mutableCopy on the array.

Comment: @DeepakR Declarations don't matter. Objective-C is dynamic.

Comment: Could you please suggest some sample code, I tried in many ways but still have not got solution.

Comment: @DeepakR `self.arrayInfo = [NSMutableArray new];`